# I want to capture SFTP Error while uploading some docs to other FTP server

Tags: shell, unix

Defined all variables above and my main code looks like this below:

```
 /usr/bin/expect<<EOD

 spawn /usr/bin/sftp  $USER@$HOST 
 expect "yes/no:"
 send "yes\r"
 expect "password:"
 send "$PASSWORD\r"
 expect "sftp>"
 send "mput *.txt $TARGET_DIR\r"
 expect "sftp>"
 send "bye\r"
```

^^ This works and uploads the file in FTP server.
Now I want to capture errors on it like FTP connection fails, FTP server not reachable,credentials not working,upload fails etc ...

How can I write such codes here using expect functionality ?

Comment: Have you consider using `scp`instead of `sftp`. It offer almost same functionality but its one line and you can easy capture the errors

Comment: No.. Since I need to delete 1 file in FTP server before executing this command...I want to have some automations in checking upload is getting succesfull or not.